# Reading Excel File from S3 and Processing in Lambda Function in C# where SNS and SQS are in between

Tags: .net, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I am using .NET 6.0 to execute Lambda Function of AWS.

The story goes like this...

Upload an Excel file with data to S3 Bucket, Create an Event Notification for that in S3 Properties section, Create an SNS for that, Create an SQS for that, Subscribe SNS from SQS and then Create Lambda Trigger with .NET 6.0 Code, where it takes SQSEvent object and processes that Excel file and puts the processed Excel file into the same S3 Bucket with different name.

In this case, while creating Lambda Function in .NET 6.0, I am able to receive the Message from SQS but the Message Body is coming as Null as in the below screenshot.

[image: SQSEvent]

How to get the Body with Content so that I can create objectKey of S3 Bucket from it?

```
var record = sqsEvent.Records[0];
var s3Event = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(messageBody)["Records"][0]["s3"];
var bucketName = s3Event["bucket"]["name"].ToString();
var objectKey = s3Event["object"]["key"].ToString();
```

But I am able to see the data in `record.S3.Bucket.Name` and `record.S3.Object.Key` when I use `S3Event` class instead of `SQSEvent` as below

[image: S3Event]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Hi there. Is there anyone to help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Seems like you missed `var messageBody = record.Body;` after `var record = sqsEvent.Records[0];` You need to retrieve the message body first before deserializing it.

**Additional Resolution:**

Also, make sure the following:

- While setting up the event notification, either select `All object create events` or `All object create events per prefix` as event type.
- Include additional information in the notification payload, such as the S3 bucket name and object key under `Configure details`.
- Allow permissions to the AWS IAM role attached to the AWS Lambda function so that the messages will be picked up and get processed as suggested by [CPK_2011](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1407900/cpk-2011).

Comment: Still the `record.Body` is coming as Null. Below is the code that I have changed. `var body = record.Body;
 var s3Event = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(body)["Records"][0]["s3"];
 var bucketName = s3Event["bucket"]["name"].ToString();
 var objectKey = s3Event["object"]["key"].ToString();`

Comment: @CPK_2011 Then maybe the issue on the configuration side. On the AWS S3 console while setting up the event notification, did you select `All object create events` or `All object create events per prefix` as event type? Also, did you include additional information in the notification payload, such as the S3 bucket name and object key under `Configure details`?

Comment: No luck. The messages are coming into Messages in flight section of SQS. But it is not moving to Lambda Function. There is no option for me to view messages in SQS because of permission problem. Once I get that on Monday, I have to figure out the approach for this. Thanks for your keen interest in my Question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found the solution for this. We need allow permissions to the Lambda role so that the messages will be picked up and get processed. Thank you so much.